# Android - Cannot read JSON string with Whitespace

Tags: android, json, whitespace

I have a problem reading string from `JSONArray`. the `try-catch` surrounding the code fire an error for element not found. I suspect it is related with the whitespace that is the character at the end of each key of the rows.

```
    JSONArray dettaglio = result.getJSONArray("dettaglioAttivita");
    for(int i = 0; i <dettaglio.length(); i++){

        JSONObject row = dettaglio.getJSONObject(i);

        String durata = row.getString("Durata ");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), durata.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**JSON RESPONSE**: Note that key string of `JSONObject` have a whitespace at the end.

```
"dettaglioAttivita": [
  {
"Unità Dididattica ": " FISICA - MODULO A - [UD-1] ",
"Tipo Attività ": " LEZ",
"Tipo Formaz. ": " Base",
"Settore ": " FIS/01 - FISICA SPERIMENTALE",
"CFU ": " 6",
"Durata ": " 48"
},
  {
"Unità Dididattica ": " FISICA - MODULO B - [UD-2] ",
"Tipo Attività ": " LEZ",
"Tipo Formaz. ": " Base",
"Settore ": " FIS/01 - FISICA SPERIMENTALE",
"CFU ": " 6",
"Durata ": " 48"
}
],
```

the exception is:
`org.json.JSONException`: no value for Durata

Comment: please post your exception.

Comment: why would that be related? Strings can contain spaces. Also please slap whoever implemented it to include the space

Answer (score 0):

Just tested in kotlin and for me it`s working with spaces:

```
import org.json.JSONObject

fun main(args : Array<String>) {


    val json = """
    {
    "dettaglioAttivita": [
        {
            "UnitàDididattica ":"FISICA - MODULO A - [UD-1]",
            "TipoAttività ":"LEZ",
            "TipoFormaz. ":"Base",
            "Settore ": "FIS/01 - FISICA SPERIMENTALE",
            "CFU":" 6",
            "Durata ":" 48"
        },
        {
            "UnitàDididattica ":"FISICA - MODULO B - [UD-2]",
            "TipoAttivit à":"LEZ",
            "TipoFormaz ":"Base",
            "Settore ":"FIS/01 - FISICA SPERIMENTALE",
            "CFU ":"6",
            "Durata ":" 48"
        }
        ]
    }
    """

    println(json)


    try {
        val jsonObject = JSONObject(json)

        val dettaglio = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dettaglioAttivita")
        for (i in 0 until dettaglio.length()) {

            val row = dettaglio.getJSONObject(i)
            println("ROW: $row")

            val durata = row.getString("Durata ")
            println("DURATA: $durata")
        }
    }catch (e : Throwable){
        println(e.toString())
    }


}
```

Printed out in for:

```
ROW: {"Durata ":" 48","UnitàDididattica ":"FISICA - MODULO A - [UD-1]","TipoFormaz. ":"Base","CFU":" 6","TipoAttività ":"LEZ","Settore ":"FIS/01 - FISICA SPERIMENTALE"}
DURATA:  48
ROW: {"Durata ":" 48","CFU ":"6","UnitàDididattica ":"FISICA - MODULO B - [UD-2]","TipoFormaz ":"Base","TipoAttivit à":"LEZ","Settore ":"FIS/01 - FISICA SPERIMENTALE"}
DURATA:  48
```